# Display artifacts under Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, display, visual-artifacts

I am getting some display artifacts under a fresh install of 12.10.

(Open image in an another tab to get the full effect)
[image]

Anyone have any idea what might be going on here or a possible solution?

My first assumption was display driver, but I've been have some difficulties getting the Nvidia binary driver to work. So I wanted to check for other possible solutions before I spend a lot of time messing with getting that to work.

Answer (score 1):

The artifact occurs when the video feed to the device isn't in sync with the display's refresh. Try changing your refresh rate of your monitor. Possibly the V-sync needs to be modified as well.

There are 2 packages that may help your situation `nvidia-current` and `nvidia-settings`
  the first is the "most up to date" driver and the second is a tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver. Both are available in the software center or synaptic or installation by the terminal using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings`

Comment: How do you change the vsync / refresh rate for a display?